# Net tension with two opposite forces

Tags: forces

What will be net tension if 10 newton force pull a body from opposite side.Will it be 10,20 or zero newton.

Comment: Have you drawn a [free body diagram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_body_diagram)?

Comment: Are you pulling from both sides with the same force? If so, does the object move? What does your real world experience tell you?

Comment: This is a Very Frequently Asked Question.  See, e.g. any of the several posts that appear on the right of this screen.

Answer (score -1):

The tension in the rope is constant and equal to 10 N. This is clear by drawing the FBD.

Comment: Just by saying ,''it is clear'',wont do the job.